# Getting the width/height of the entire browser in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Does anybody here know what the Javascript call is to get the width/height of the entire browser window (including nav, menu, etc?)

I know there is `outerWidth`, `outerHeight` in FF, Safari and other browsers.

Answer (score 3):

This also could be helpful, depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish:

window.moveTo(0,0);
window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);
var navButtonsEtcHeight = screen.height - window.innerHeight;
var navButtonsEtcWidth = screen.width - window.innerWidth;

Note: For browser-independent solution to "window.innerHeight" support, see [this link](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow)

Then you have the answer you're looking for -- mind you, with the downside of the non-fullscreen user seeing their window bounce around the screen first.

Comment: Unfortunately `window.resizeTo` is no longer reliable in IE. For example, it doesn't work if tabbed browsing is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

It's a variation of DreadPirateShawn's answer. Tested on IE7 and Chrome8. Originally appearing on [Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web/Web_Languages/JavaScript/Q_20917957.html).

```
function getWindowSize() {
    var wW, wH;
    if (window.outerWidth) {
        wW = window.outerWidth;
        wH = window.outerHeight;
    } else {
        var cW = document.body.offsetWidth;
        var cH = document.body.offsetHeight;
        window.resizeTo(500,500);
        var barsW = 500 - document.body.offsetWidth;
        var barsH = 500 - document.body.offsetHeight;
        wW = barsW + cW;
        wH = barsH + cH;
        window.resizeTo(wW,wH);
    }
    return { width: wW, height: wH };
}
```

Comment: This function creates 6 global variables which you really don't want to do. Also it would be cleaner to check for window.outerWidth/outerHeight first vs. checking for document.all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible.

It might be worth reviewing [Chapter 14 of O'Reilly's: JavaScript - The Definitive Guide](http://books.google.com/books?id=2weL0iAfrEMC&lpg=PA275&ots=_8ZBvAU3aH&dq=window.outerwidth%20internet%20explorer&pg=PA270), particularly section 14.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want

```
document.body.offsetWidth
document.body.offsetHeight
```

Comment: That's still giving me the inner height of the browser (just the page). I want everything include the nav, buttons etc

Comment: I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: actually, you might be able to. because window.screen.availHeight gives the height of screen minus the taskbar. so if you do some subtracting, you might be able to figure out the nav bar and tabs size, assuming the window is in normal, fully laid out edge to edge. Then, once you have the nav & tab bar size (height) you can add that to or subtract that from whatever you want. what on earth is up with IE not giving out screen size information?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use

```
width: window.outerWidth
height: window.outerHeight
```

you can use jquery so it wont be undefined in ie. You might try and figure out there screen size first and then using the dimensions of the browser figure out the precise size.

doc:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/dimensions/outerHeight

Comment: -1 This isn't what he wants. jQuery's OuterHeight/Width includes border & padding (http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/outerHeight), but he wants nav, buttons, etc. included