# javascript: getting OUTER (real) browser window height?

Tags: javascript

i know there is stuff like window innerHeight etc.
Can I retrieve the real window height of my browser (with all it's toolbars etc.)??
crossbrowser if possible?

regards matt

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045050/getting-the-width-height-of-the-entire-browser-in-ie (hint: IE requires a hack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most browsers, you can use `window.outerWidth` and `window.outerHeight`.

However, it's not generally possible in IE. It used to be possible to use a hacky solution involving `window.resizeTo` but that method no longer works in various situations, including whenever tabbed browsing is enabled.