# Javascript -- Increase window height by one pixel -- Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, resize

I'm working on a Chromium extension that runs a context script on a constrained window, and want to increase the window height by one pixel (I need the page to reposition, since I'm injecting HTML into it).

I'm attempting to use the following code:

`window.resizeTo(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight + 1);`

but this shrinks the window (I suspect because Chromium `resizeTo` sets window size, but `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` gets the size of the TabContents window pane (not including the top bar and border).

How can I either get the proper size or properly resize the window?  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: can't you use the values `outerWidth` and `outerHeight`?  I'm not experienced with javascript but a quick search seems to suggest that those properties exist as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually want window.outerHeight/window.outerWidth, which includes all of the browser UI.

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly.  Is outerHeight a standard property on all browsers?

Comment: Not in IE < 9.  Check the solution at the bottom of this page:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045050/getting-the-width-height-of-the-entire-browser-in-ie