# How to find the browser height including the toolbars and buttons with javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, height

Is there a way to find the browser height with the toolbars and buttons of the browser, not only the window or document height?

Comment: if you are planning to manage site with screen resolution you can use screen.height;
screen.width;

Comment: not true, that's the whole screen, I believe he only wants the window, so: window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth

Comment: @tiagoboldt not innerHeight. i need the whole browser height with toolbars and buttons, innerHeight only gives the inner height.

Answer (score 4):

For the size of the viewport, you use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.  For the whole window, including decorations, use `window.outerWidth` and `window.outerHeight`.  Then, all you need to do is subtract one from the other.

Edit: There is no supported way of doing this in IE8 and older. This is explained in [this article](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlbbqca.php) and also provides a workaround which involves resizing the browser window.  There is also [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045050/getting-the-width-height-of-the-entire-browser-in-ie/1045407#1045407).

Comment: window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight is not compatible with ie8 and older versions, i need a cross browser solution.

Comment: There is no supported way of doing that. See my updated answer.