# Get Browser Width and Height Including Toolbars and Menu Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

i need Js / Jquery which returns me browser width and height including height / width of toolbar and etc..

It will also work if i can get browser's toolbar height / width separately...

Can any body have any idea on this??

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291780/how-to-find-the-browser-height-including-the-toolbars-and-buttons-with-javascrip

Comment: As I know there seems no way to do that. But I'm curious why you need that?

Comment: i need to do some calculation based on browser size and user's screen resolution ... and need to find out some proportional width / height bases on them... i get one script which returns me window size including toolbars and all.. in that case my calculation goes wrong... that's why i needed this... :)

Comment: thanks Tx3 for your help, i read somewhere that window.outerWidth do not work in IE8 and older browsers... so can we have some browser compatible solution

Answer (score 2):

You should look at `window.outerHeight` and `window.outerWidth`

[See here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlbbqca.php)

The backwards compatible way is quite a bit longer.

[See here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm)

Comment: thanks @CaldwellYSR , i found then window.outerHeight and window.outerWidth do not work in IE8 and older browsers... can we get some other cross-browser solution.. ?