# Live Detect Browser Size - jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Is there a jQuery plugin or a way using straight JavaScript to detect browser size.

I'd prefer it is the results were 'live', so if the width or height changes, so would the results.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
function jsUpdateSize(){
    // Get the dimensions of the viewport
    var width = window.innerWidth ||
                document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
                document.body.clientWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight ||
                 document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
                 document.body.clientHeight;

    document.getElementById('jsWidth').innerHTML = width;  // Display the width
    document.getElementById('jsHeight').innerHTML = height;// Display the height
};
window.onload = jsUpdateSize;       // When the page first loads
window.onresize = jsUpdateSize;     // When the browser changes size
```

**jQuery**

```
function jqUpdateSize(){
    // Get the dimensions of the viewport
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();

    $('#jqWidth').html(width);      // Display the width
    $('#jqHeight').html(height);    // Display the height
};
$(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);    // When the page first loads
$(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);     // When the browser changes size
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/Uvh6e/1/)

**Edit:** Updated the JavaScript code to support IE8 and earlier.

Comment: When the demo runs in jsfiddle, it reports the size of the IFrame that the demo runs in. When the demo runs in a standalone page, it reports the size of the browser viewport. I tested it both ways. Seemed to work fine.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about the iframe. Thanks!

Comment: Is there also a way to detect the actual browser height and width?

Comment: To get the browser size including the menu and toolbar, use `window.outerWidth` and `window.outerHeight`. There's no such option available for IE8 and earlier, however. See the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291780/how-to-find-the-browser-height-including-the-toolbars-and-buttons-with-javascrip

Comment: Thanks for your code, but I wouldn't use "document.body.clientHeight" as a fallback since it gives wrong values in several browsers (unless that value is actually correct in browsers that don't support the other two variables; which are those, BTW?).

Comment: I needed this in order to understand why my media queries were not working for the iPad. Thank you SO MUCH. BTW, on the iPad, when you change orientation, the width remains the same... so therein lies the problem. I need to use 'orientation' in my media query in order to properly target iPads.
Your scripts work beautifully. Thank you for the JSfiddle. One interesting observation: when you pinch and zoom in on the iPad, the values change for the JS, but not for jQuery! So it's nice to have both scripts.

Answer (score 6):

you can use

```
function onresize (){
   var h = $(window).height(), w= $(window).width();
   $('#resultboxid').html('height= ' + h + ' width: ' w);
}
 $(window).resize(onresize ); 

 onresize ();// first time;
```

html:

```
<span id=resultboxid></span>
```

Comment: How would I display the results then?

Comment: on each onresize call you can change the content of your result box. by the way what information are you showing. If you are showing height and width then simply use :$('#resultboxid').html('height:' + h + ' width: ' w);

Comment: I'm just looking to display the width and height.

Comment: @user1658756 I modified onresize method. you can change the code according to your requirement or you should share your code so that I can make changes according to your code

Comment: "Hmm, it's not working"

I'm of the opinion that all code snippets on Stack Overflow should be shared with a link to JSFiddle or CodePen, or at least those that use it should have a 10-fold increase in their reputation!

Comment: +1 if not working use this line 
$('#resultboxid').html('height= ' + h + ' width: ' +  w);
concatenation issue noticed in answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should return the visible area:

```
document.body.offsetWidth
document.body.offsetHeight
```

I guess this is always equal to the browser size?

Answer (score 2):

use width and height variable anywhere you want... when ever browser size change it will change variable value too..

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    width = $(this).width());
    height = $(this).height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this `window.innerHeight; window.innerWidth` `$(window).height(); $(window).width()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding even listener on re-size like

```
window.addEventListener('resize',CheckBrowserSize,false);
function CheckBrowserSize() 
{
    var ResX= document.body.offsetHeight;
    var ResY= document.body.offsetWidth;
}
```