# Javascript to use different value for mobile vs desktop in gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slight problem with Javascript (or jQuery?).

Its part of a gallery from codrops.com. Its just a small part of it. Its the part Im having trouble with. (see it at kuglerdesign.com/gallery.html - still a site under construction)

```
// stops slideshow
    _stopSlideshow = function( pause ) {

        if( Gamma.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        Gamma.isAnimating = true;

        clearTimeout( Gamma.slideshowtimeout );
        if( !pause ) {

            Gamma.slideshow = false;
            Gamma.svplay.removeClass( 'gamma-btn-sspause' );
            Gamma.svMargins = Gamma.settings.svMarginsVH;
            _toggleControl( Gamma.svclose, 'on' );
            _toggleControl( Gamma.svnavprev, 'on', { left : 20 } );
            _toggleControl( Gamma.svnavnext, 'on', { right : 60 } );
            _svResizeImage( function() {

                Gamma.isAnimating = false;

            } );
```

However, there is a problem with the arrows that allow you to see previous and next picture. It happens when you tell the gallery to start the slideshow (which moves the arrows to -60px left and right (not seen here), respectively) and then stop the slideshow. The Javascript reads that it should move the arrows back into position to 60px right and 20px left.

But, on a mobile 60px is too much, and on a desktop 20px(for mobile) is too little (at start it uses CSS class, where it is different for mobile and desktop).

I was hoping to be able to write an if statement that would say if the screen is smaller than 760px, it would move by 20px, otherwise it would take 60px.

I wrote something like this:
_toggleControl( Gamma.svnavnext, 'on', { **if (screen.width < 760) {right : 20;} else {right :60 }** );

(rest of code still same)

Would that ever have a chancce of working without adding too much more code?

Comment: You should try to stay away from checking this with js and instead use css media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries and http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

Put in a simple 'if' statement and abstract the values:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 760) {
    var offsetLeft = 8;
    var offsetRight = 20;
} else {
    var offsetLeft = 20;
    var offsetRight = 60;
}
_toggleControl( Gamma.svnavprev, 'on', { left : offsetLeft } );
_toggleControl( Gamma.svnavnext, 'on', { right : offsetRight } );
```

Long (more correct) answer:

Use a relative unit of space, like `em` or `%`. That way it'll always show correctly regardless of screen size. Using the fixed unit `px`, you'll have to hard-code different amounts for each possible screen size (which, nowadays, varies a lot what with tablets and phones in all shapes and sizes).

It looks like all of your CSS is currently using the `px` units and made responsive using JavaScript (I see some percentages but those look set using JavaScript as well). If you need an introduction to using scalable units of space (you should always use scalable units unless you have no other option, which rarely happens), I direct you to [this excellent beginner's article by Kyle Schaeffer](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/).

Alternatively, detect the device's screen dimensions and use a different CSS file based on that. This depends on your layout, of course, as it is increasingly more common to design in a mobile-first approach and simply scale up to desktop sizes using the aforementioned relative units. This design method removes the need of separate layouts for different devices.

Also, if all you're trying to do is hide the arrows temporarily, I suggest simply setting `display: none` in CSS using JavaScript to hide them and `display: block` to make them reappear. A simple way of doing this would be this:

```
var arrows = document.getElementByClassName('arrow'); // assuming the arrows have a common class name called 'arrow'
for (i=0; i<arrows.length; i++) {
    arrows[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I pasted the code (took a while to realise you showed where to paste it...) and its working like a charm!

Comment: Sorry, worte a bigger comment but hit enter at start, only allows edit for 5min so lost it all.

(Again...) Just wanted to say thanks again and for CSS advice. I consider myself pretty good at CSS but useless in Javascript. The CSS galleries usually run real slow though (or have browser compatibility issues), so  I opted for a javascript gallery. I would usually use percentages and always try to use EM instead of px, however, I just missed the easiest fix of using a percentage. So thanks for your answer again, well thought out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach: [Live Detect Browser Size - jQuery / JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781205/live-detect-browser-size-jquery-javascript)

Followed by updating the _toggleControl function within a check of the browser size.