# jquery - moving multiple instances of div across screen at random Y-position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to detect clicks and move elements from off-screen right to off-screen left with jquery.

I achieved the general idea already ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drthmwbo/)) but only for one div, once.

HTML:

```
<div class = "outer">         
    <div id = "box">       
    </div>             
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { 
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 500px;
}

#box{
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background: #FF00FF;
   position: absolute;
   right: -100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random()*bodyHeight));
        $('#box').css('top', randPosY);
        $("#box").animate({left: '-100px'}, 5000);
    });
});
```

1. How can make a new instance div appear (at random y-position) per click on the document?
2. My random y-position is calculated in jQuery the following way, but gets its value from my css `height: 500px;` - how can I make this value responsive?

Comment: responsive or random?

Comment: In the example I assume the height of the body to be 500px. The random function in query calculates a random y position between 0 and 500 already. However I want the value to size represent the actual height of the window... currently checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781205/live-detect-browser-size-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function constructor to add object instances of a div, where each one uses `.box` class instead of `#box`:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drthmwbo/2/)

```
function SlidingDiv(bodyHeight){
    this.randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random()*bodyHeight));
    this.$div = $("<div>").addClass('box').appendTo('.outer');
};

SlidingDiv.prototype.slide = function(){
    this.$div.css('top', this.randPosY);
    this.$div.animate({left: '-100px'}, 5000);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        var bodyHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
        var div = new SlidingDiv(bodyHeight);
        div.slide();
    });
});
```

Edit: To remove divs, you could try the complete function:

```
SlidingDiv.prototype.slide = function() {
    this.$div.css('top', this.randPosY);
    this.$div.animate({
        left: '-100px',
        duration: 5000,
        complete: function() { this.$div.remove(); }.bind(this)
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks for that! that did the trick. The boxes are still present off-screen. How could I clear them not to fill up cache? It seems like the .hide() function only makes them invisible but doesn't actually remove them from the canvas.

Comment: Thanks @Data - the updated code seems to ignore the 'duration' though. And I noticed on Chrome the start position off screen does not work properly. I tried changing css and script but the box would just start at the left of the screen. Any idea what's the cause?

Comment: Seems to have to do something with `right: -100px` in the CSS and `left:'-100px'` in the jQuery because putting `left: 1000px` does change the start position whereas changing the `right` attribute in the CSS has no effect on the output

Comment: OK i fixed problem 2 by changing the startPosition via jQuery and the `$ (window).width()` function so it also works in Chrome now https://jsfiddle.net/drthmwbo/7/