# Get the current browser window center

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the browser window height so I can find the center position?

I only need the window height, not the web page height.

I tried `$(window).height() / 2` but it only works if the browser has focus from the top of the page. If I scroll down I get the wrong center.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the y value of the center of the current viewable area, use:

```
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() / 2
```

I tried it on this page, by opening up the Web Inspector and entering:

```
$('<p>').text('test').appendTo('body').css({position: 'absolute', top: $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() / 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the body's height needs to be in brackets for it to work properly:

```
var center = $("body").scrollTop() + ($("body").height() / 2);
```

However, if you're making a popup dialog, it's better to detect if the user is not on a mobile device then use the CSS "position: fixed". You detect for mobile devices because Mobile Safari doesn't understand fixed positioning in iOS versions before 5. Use this code for the detection:

```
var isMobile = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mobile/") != -1;
```

Ad@m

Comment: No, the height calculation doesn't need to be in parenthesis. In JavaScript, multiplication is higher than addition in precedence. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/operator_precedence#Table Good point about `position: fixed`.

Comment: I don't think the body height part does need to be in brackets - Javascript's operator precedence will do the `.` then the `/` then the `+` - so `$("body").scrollTop() + $("body").height() / 2;` is the same as `($("body").scrollTop()) + (($("body").height()) / 2))`

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.outerHeight` and `window.outerWidth`, which works in FF5 (and possibly earlier versions) and Chrome, but not in IE9. From googling it seems that this bit of info is not easy to get by in IE.

Also see [this other question dealing with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1045050/269126).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var iframe = '<html><head><style>body, html {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}</style></head><body><iframe src="' + src + '" style="height:calc(100% - 4px);width:calc(100% - 4px)"></iframe></html></body>';       
    var w = 700;
    var h = 600;

    var leftCenter = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var leftWindowMargin = leftCenter - (w / 2);
    var topCenter = window.innerHeight / 2;
    var topWindowMargin = topCenter - (h / 2);

    var win = window.open("", "", "width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",resizable=no,top=" + topWindowMargin + ",left=" + leftWindowMargin + ";");
    win.document.write(iframe);
```

Comment: It's advisable to avoid `document.write`. Reference https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).