# JavaScript window.open Correct Size for all browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, window

So, basically, I've got a search results screen with an "Open" button for each result. Clicking that button should open a new window with a streamed database BLOB displayed.

I have everything working properly except for the correct sizing of the newly opened window.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
window.open('View.aspx', 'Document', 'width=' + screen.width + ', height=' + screen.availHeight + ');
```

This seems to work correctly on IE, but it fails on Chrome. It seems that Chrome is setting the innerHeight, not the outerHeight, but I can't seem to find a good cross-browser way to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the window outer size [Getting the width/height of the entire browser in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4355458/669527) (there is a solution for other browsers too) and correct size of the window with [resizeTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp) or [resizeBy()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeby.asp).