# Can any browser open a new window larger then the screen size?

Tags: javascript, macos, internet-explorer, operating-system, cross-browser

One of windows in my application has the size set by administrator. I need to be sure that the window does not open with any border out of screen. By my experiments the window fills the screen when the required size in `window.open` (`resizeTo`) is larger. However, is it true for any resolution and any browser (operating system)?

**Edit**

May I hope that the size cannot be larger when `outerWidth` (`outerHeight`) is not supported? ( [Getting the width/height of the entire browser in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045050/getting-the-width-height-of-the-entire-browser-in-ie) )

**Edit 2**
I have made tests on Fedora 16 (LXDE, Plasma, Gnome) with Konqueror and Firefox. I did not succeed to open a window larger then screen.

Comment: in gnome3 or unity you can resize window more than screen resolution.
in window 7 window manager doesnt give you this ability.

Comment: So it seems that it is more an operating system related problem than a browser?

Comment: mostly yes then no, contolling window size is an system window manager responsibility. Maby some browsers are getting to control size them self, but in system - browser is a window so its render depends on system your are workin in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not manage to find a way how to do it and it seems that there is no useful proposal (for about a month). So I conclude it is not possible (or not simply possible on major operating system/browsers).

Answer (score 1):

@vanH: then you need to provide height and width parameter

```
window.open("", "mywindow1", "status=1,width=2050,height=2150");
```

Comment: But does the window open larger then screen when the width or height are larger?

Comment: no window size will not be grater than browser but you can open window of less size than browser window

Comment: The new window size does not depend on the original window size. I have tested it a minute ago (Windows 7 and IE 9 and Firefox 11).